# Do ActiveRecord queries search through the database while using rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-activerecord, factory-bot

I am trying to test my rails models. Some of them have find_by queries inside of the model. Outside of RSpec, it seems to work fine. But doesn't seem to have a database to search through when using RSpec. I am also using FactoryGirl to set up factories. It seems that the database it searches through is for the factories that were created. I am unsure why this is and I just want to have a better understanding of what is going on. Thank you.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? Can show show some code to support your question?

Comment: Apart of setting up (a.k.a. defining factories) you need to create the objects in your specs. So when you have `:user` factory defined, create it like this: `before { create(:user) }` or `let!(:user) { create(:user) }` - only then the factory will store the object in the Database

Comment: jack-nie was able to answer my question. Basically, I didn't realize that when I am using rSpec, I am only connected to my test database instead of my development database.

Answer (score 1):

When using RSpec to test your app, then your database environment is `test`, so you're connected to your test database.

Otherwise, let's say you're in development mode, then you're connected to your development database.